Warning after upgrade to 5.72.1 wordpress re Deprecation Permission 'view payment tokens'
Wordpress: 6.5.2
CiviCRM: 5.72.1 (just upgraded and get the warning below now)
PHP: 8.1
MySQL: 8
Warning error on any CiviCRM screen:
Deprecated: Permission 'view payment tokens' should be declared with 'label' and 'description' keys. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/ Caller: CRM_Core_Permission::assembleBasicPermissions in mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1129
Deprecated: Permission 'edit payment tokens' should be declared with 'label' and 'description' keys. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/ Caller: CRM_Core_Permission::assembleBasicPermissions in mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1129
Can anybody help me with this warning. It leads to 2 x warnings being displayed on every page displayed. Also I noticed that when I went to check the eWay payment processor CiviCRM would NOT display the configured record. Note: Once I commented out the line 1129 as per above it would display the eWay record. Have tested a live donation with the commented out code and it works currently.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Can you find in the code file under the extension or module for 'edit payment tokens' is from which extension or module?

Found the following in eWay wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/au.com.agileware.ewayrecurring/eWAYRecurring.php as follows:  `                               /**

Implements hook_civicrm_permission

@param $permissions permissions list to add to
*/
function ewayrecurring_civicrm_permission(&$permissions) {
$permissions['view payment tokens'] = E::ts('CiviContribute: view payment tokens');
$permissions['edit payment tokens'] = E::ts('CiviContribute: edit payment tokens');
}`


I have submitted a PR for the fix, you can apply the patch or wait for the maintainer to merge and release a new version.
HTH
Pradeep

Implemented fix and tested with success!
